# How to access file under C Drive in server from client machine?

Tags: java, html, file

My client machine(mobile device) want to access pdf files from server where these files located under C or E drive. I've tried to access files under tomcat and it's successful. But I've no idea how to do this.

Comment: If it was successful and secure, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: cos other web service is using these files and they are accessing from E drive.

Comment: so .... what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You `should not` access a server drive directly from a client. It is a security loop hole.

Your server must expose the `pdf as a webservice`, for the client to be able to download it or use it.

Comment: The "cos other web service is using these files and they are accessing from E drive" comment above is very confusing. You'd almost think the OP was already trying to implement a webservice without doing the logical thing of mentioning that.